# Pandas: replace specific characters in column based on condition using groupby

Tags: python, pandas, replace, group-by, conditional-statements

I have the following dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
'ACCOUNT': [1, 1, 2, 2], 
'ASSET_CLASS': ['11201XX FI CHF', '11201XX FI CHF', 
                '12201XX FI EUR', '12201XX FI EUR',
               ],
})

display(df)

    ACCOUNT ASSET_CLASS     
0   1       11201XX FI CHF  
1   1       11201XX FI CHF  
2   2       12201XX FI EUR  
3   2       12201XX FI EUR
```

For a list of accounts, I'd like to replace "XX" in column "ASSET_CLASS" by "01" and "02", respectively using the groupby function and "ACCOUNT" as groupby-variable. In addition, the name of the value should then be adjusted according to the assigned value. For instance, if "01" ("02"), then "FI CHF" equals "FI CHF Gov" ("FI CHF Corporate"). This is how it should look like:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'ACCOUNT': [1, 1, 2, 2], 
    'ASSET_CLASS': ['1120101 FI CHF Gov', '1120102 FI CHF Corporate',
                    '1220101 FI EUR Gov', '1120102 FI EUR Corporate',
                   ],
})

display(df)

    ACCOUNT ASSET_CLASS
0   1       1120101 FI CHF Gov
1   1       1120102 FI CHF Corporate
2   2       1220101 FI EUR Gov
3   2       1120102 FI EUR Corporate
```

Thanks a lot in advance for any suggestions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Code**

```
s1 = df.groupby('ACCOUNT').cumcount().add(1).astype('str').str.zfill(2)
m = {'01': ' Gov', '02': ' Corporate'}
s2 = df['ASSET_CLASS'].str.split('XX')
df['ASSET_CLASS'] = s2.str[0] + s1 + s2.str[1] + s1.map(m)
```

df

```
    ACCOUNT ASSET_CLASS
0   1       1120101 FI CHF Gov
1   1       1120102 FI CHF Corporate
2   2       1220101 FI EUR Gov
3   2       1220102 FI EUR Corporate
```

---

update my answer with additional question

when account has CHF & EUR both, and you want split them use following code

example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'ACCOUNT': [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2], 
    'ASSET_CLASS': ['11201XX FI CHF', '11201XX FI CHF', 
                    '12201XX FI EUR', '12201XX FI EUR',
                    '12201XX FI EUR', '12201XX FI EUR',
                   ],
})
```

code:

```
s1 = df.groupby(['ACCOUNT', df['ASSET_CLASS'].str.split(' ').str[-1]]).cumcount()\
       .add(1).astype('str').str.zfill(2)
m = {'01': ' Gov', '02': ' Corporate'}
s2 = df['ASSET_CLASS'].str.split('XX')
df['ASSET_CLASS'] = s2.str[0] + s1 + s2.str[1] + s1.map(m)
```

df

```
    ACCOUNT ASSET_CLASS
0   1       1120101 FI CHF Gov
1   1       1120102 FI CHF Corporate
2   1       1220101 FI EUR Gov
3   1       1220102 FI EUR Corporate
4   2       1220101 FI EUR Gov
5   2       1220102 FI EUR Corporate
```

Comment: I like this solution

Comment: Thanks a lot Kim! Another question: what if an account has both FI CHF and EUR? Just tested it on my own, and it seems that only the first two records are being considered.

Comment: @Ben If you have additional questions, please provide additional examples.

Answer (score 1):

@Panda Kim: Sure. Here's what I had in mind. Say I have the following dataframe:

```
 df = pd.DataFrame({
    'ACCOUNT': [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2], 
    'ASSET_CLASS': ['11201XX FI CHF', '11201XX FI CHF', 
                    '12201XX FI EUR', '12201XX FI EUR',
                    '12201XX FI EUR', '12201XX FI EUR',
                   ],
})

display(df)


ACCOUNT ASSET_CLASS
0   1   11201XX FI CHF
1   1   11201XX FI CHF
2   1   12201XX FI EUR
3   1   12201XX FI EUR
4   2   12201XX FI EUR
5   2   12201XX FI EUR
```

Using your provided input, I obtain the following:

```
s1 = df.groupby('ACCOUNT').cumcount().add(1).astype('str').str.zfill(2)
m = {'01': ' Gov', '02': ' Corporate'}
s2 = df['ASSET_CLASS'].str.split('XX')
df['ASSET_CLASS'] = s2.str[0] + s1 + s2.str[1] + s1.map(m)
df

    ACCOUNT ASSET_CLASS
0   1       1120101 FI CHF Gov
1   1       1120102 FI CHF Corporate
2   1       NaN
3   1       NaN
4   2       1220101 FI EUR Gov
5   2       1220102 FI EUR Corporate
```

Is it able to adjust your code by considering the possibility that an account might have more than two asset classes? Ideally, this is what I'd like to get:

```
    ACCOUNT ASSET_CLASS
0   1       1120101 FI CHF Gov
1   1       1120102 FI CHF Corporate
2   1       1220101 FI EUR Gov
3   1       1220102 FI EUR Corporate
4   2       1220101 FI EUR Gov
5   2       1220102 FI EUR Corporate
```

Comment: i update my answer.

Comment: perfect, exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot!! :)